# Djangoで定数ファイルを環境別に振り分けたい

Tags: python, django

Djangoで定数ファイルを定義したいです。
また、その定数ファイルは環境別に定義したいのですが、可能でしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

いくつか方法があります

1. settingsを分ける
2. 環境変数で定数を指定する(honchoやsystemdで環境変数を与える)
3. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-constance 等を使う

参考: https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/configuration/